# New fish session on iTerm2 get (standard_in) 1: parse error

Tags: fish, iterm2

I recently updated iTerm2 to version 3.2.4 and then to 3.2.5 and I get `(standard_in) 1: parse error` every time I start a new ***fish*** session. (on both versions - nothing on the previous ones).

I use `fortune -a -s` as greeting, and don't think that is the cause of the error.

My version of fish is 2.7.1

[image]

Renaming ***config.fish*** file, "solved" the error! I believe the real problem is in ***init.fish***.

My ***config.fish*** file :

```
set -gx OMF_PATH /Users/<my-user>/.local/share/omf
set -gx OMF_CONFIG /Users/<my-user>/.config/omf
source $OMF_PATH/init.fish
set -g fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length 5
```

My ***init.fish*** file was never altered, so the file is still equal to the original one: [init.fish](https://github.com/oh-my-fish/oh-my-fish/blob/master/init.fish)

Comment: Insufficient data. But one possibility is you are doing something like `cmd_that_produces_posix_shell_output | source`. Also, if you have iTerm shell integration enabled does disabling that make the problem go away? What if you temporarily rename your *~/.config/fish* dir?

Comment: @KurtisRader I do not have shell integration. I have updated my question with what you suggested. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think it more likely the problem is with an OMF plugin, not the OMF code itself. Can you disable each plugin one at a time to pinpoint which one is the cause of the error?

Comment: @KurtisRader you were wright! It was a package named ***battery*** that was causing that. I uninstalled it because I don't use it. Problem solved! Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question has been answered in comments.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue although it didn't affect me from starting a fish shell. However, I believe the similar outcome was related. When I added quotes in certain spots, and used brackets to separate a variable to be expanded before appending the rest of a string to it that seemed to work. In your case try editing config.fish like so:

```sh
set -gx OMF_PATH "/Users/anonirato/.local/share/omf"
set -gx OMF_CONFIG "/Users/anonirato/.config/omf"
source "{$OMF_PATH}/init.fish"
set -g fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length 5
```

Let me know if that does anything for ya. If not, then I will dig deeper and edit my answer.

Comment: as I said in the comments of question, replying to Kurtis Rader, what was causing the problem was a fish package named ***battery***. I removed it and never tried installing again as I didn't use it. Maybe your answer could solve the problem without having to uninstall it.